# (Excel Vba) Simple Copy & Paste of ranges ,but with random values

Tags: excel, vba, random, copy, paste

I cannt understand, why my excel  script does not work anymore.. 
I need to do simple copy Paste function,

First, I have 1 value (Mean)  which  is generated and it changes randomly after any action (Very important point!)

So , I need a kind of "simulation",  means  to copy the value  and put it in another worksheet, after that the excel is refreshing automatically and I get a new mean-value..

This process should be repeated 1000 times. It means i will have 1000 different values at the end, because of random changes of my mean-value

I have a script, which works perfect for this purpose.

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Worksheet2").Select
Cells(4, 23).Select
Selection.Copy
'
Sheets("Worksheet3").Select
For i = 1 To 1000
    Cells(1 + i, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
'
End Sub
```

Now, 
I have not  only one cell (my mean-value) but two! ( median from the same data)

It means, now it should copy two cells simultaneously (range)  and paste than in the new worksheet, in the new range. 
So, it is the same process, like in my script, but with two cells

a kind of this..

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Fracht Modell Roh").Select

Range("W4:X4").Select
Selection.Copy
'
Sheets("Ergebnisse").Select
For i = 1 To 100
    Range("A2:B2" & 1 + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CalculateFull
Next i
'

End Sub
```

I tried to do it with range()  BUT!!! it doesnt refresh my mean and median values anymore ... or something else... so I get 1000 times the SAME!!  value after the script running.

I can not understand, what is his problem. Why in first case it works perfect, and if I do the same task with range, it seems to copy the same value about 1000 times, but not refreshing or changing it.

pleas, I hope, anybody could help me
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Fracht Modell Roh").Select
Range("W4:X4").Select
Selection.Copy
'
Sheets("Ergebnisse").Select
For i = 1 To 1000
    Range("A" & i + 1 & ":B" & i + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
```

However, your code doesn't need the `Select` statement to work, that will just let the code jump through sheets over and over without reasons. I might rather write it like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Fracht Modell Roh").Range("W4:X4").Copy
'
With Sheets("Ergebnisse")
For i = 1 To 1000
    .Range("A" & i + 1 & ":B" & i + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
End With
```

Same thing for your other code snippet, the one for a single random value:

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Worksheet2").Cells(4, 23).Copy
'
With Sheets("Worksheet3")
For i = 1 To 1000
    .Cells(1 + i, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next i
End With
```

Moreover, if as I imagine the two cells in the first sheet contains two random functions `=RAND()`, why you don't directly write them in VBA?

```
With Sheets("Ergebnisse")
For i = 1 To 1000
    .Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Rnd
    .Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Rnd
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Matteo!
 Now, I think it does correctly what I want. namely i get various values)